# Django UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, drupal-7, passwords

I try to implement [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3030/) hasher in order to be able to authenticate user who are imported from drupal 7.

So I put the hasher in the settings.py as follows:

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (

```
'myproj.drupal_hasher.DrupalPasswordHasher', #drupal hasher

'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',

'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
 )
```

However it does not authenticate imported users from drupal and for users who are created in Django I get:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the trackback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'article',
 'photo',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_markdown',
 'haystack')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mario/myproj/myauth/views.py" in auth_view
  16.     user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  60.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  17.             if user.check_password(password):
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in check_password
  237.         return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py" in check_password
  63.         setter(password)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in setter
  235.             self.set_password(raw_password)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in set_password
  227.         self.password = make_password(raw_password)
File "/home/mario/.myprojenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py" in make_password
  85.     return hasher.encode(password, salt)
File "/home/mario/myproj/myproj/drupal_hasher.py" in encode
  81.         encoded_hash = self._apply_hash(password, self._digests[digest], settings)
File "/home/mario/myproj/myproj/drupal_hasher.py" in _apply_hash
  68.             password_hash = digest(password_hash + password).digest()

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /auth/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to  .decode('utf-8') to  encoded_hash, but get the same result.

All source and destination database tables are converted to utf8_unicode_ci. and I have added

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

On the top of all relevant pages.

I am stock on this problem for days so really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, append 'drupal$' to the imported password:

(as drupal is the default hasher, user 1 has already drupal$ hashed to his password)

```
UPDATE djangodb.auth_user SET password=CONCAT('drupal$',password) where id<>1;
```

Then it turned out that I had to add

```
password = password.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

At the begining of both 'encode' and 'verify' methods in DrupalPasswordHasher class because the password in my app is encoded as utf but the hasher expects ascii.

These simple points did the trick.